# Jquery Validation: Call Valid without displaying errors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using JQuery Validation plugin, I am trying to call the .valid() method without the side-effects of displaying error messages on screen. I have tried a number of scenarios with no success, my latest being:

```
$('#signup').validate({
            showErrors: function() { return; },
            errorElement: "",
            errorClass: "",
            errorPlacement: function() { },
            invalidHandler: function() { },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) { },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) { }
        });

$('#displayPurposes').text("Valid: " + $("#EMailAddress_EmailAddress").valid());
```

Whilst the .valid() call is working correctly it is still causing side-effects of displaying error messages.

I don't want this to happen, help please.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Well instead of trying to disable any error placement made by the plugin you could use CSS to 'force' hiding the create error messages elements. Something like:

```
label.myvalidationclass { display: none !important; }
```

Where `myvalidationclass` is either the default error class name or your own.

I'm aware it is not a very nice solution but in my opinion, displaying error messages is one of the core feature of the plugin.

d.

Comment: Apologies for the very late acceptance, but if I recall I did end up with something similar to hacking the css.

Answer (score 73):

You can do this without using CSS hacks by calling `checkForm()`.

```
var isValid = $('#signup').validate().checkForm(); // true|false
```

`checkForm()` does not trigger UI changes.

However, there is one side effect. Form fields will now be validated on change/focus/blur, which may be undesirable. You can disable this behavior by resetting the `submitted` object:

```
$('#signup').validate().submitted = {};
```

Which results in:

```
var validate = $('#signup').validate(); // Get validate instance
var isValid = validate.checkForm(); // Valid?
validate.submitted = {}; // Reset immediate form field checking mode
```

Comment: +1: This is a far nicer solution, and allows the flexibility to only validate without messages when required.

Comment: This is solution I used and I can recommend to everyone.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if a certain input is valid without highlighting it?

Comment: @simaglei you should create a new SO question for that

Comment: This solution kind of messes up the generated HTML so that it no longer shows up in the same way. Could be an issue for CSS rules.

Comment: Best solution @Blaise Thank you so much